# then block isn't get called in chained promises

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm working on retrying some async calls in JS. When simplified and rewritten to `setTimeout` the logic looks like this:

```js
let error = true

let promise = null

const runPromise = (value) => new Promise((res) => {
    if (!error) {
        res()
        return
    }

    if (promise) {
        return promise.then(() => {
            return runPromise(value) 
        })
    }

    promise = new Promise((res2) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            promise = null
            console.log(value)
            error = false
            res2()
        }, 1000)
    }).then(() => res())
})

runPromise(1).then(() => { console.log(1) })
runPromise(2).then(() => { console.log(2) })
runPromise(3).then(() => { console.log(3) })
```

Why `then` blocks for `runPromise(2)` and `runPromise(3)` never got called?

Comment: probably because you are mutating the same `promise` that's shared between all of them

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: @Federkun yeah, it makes sense. do you have any idea how I can attach them so the chain doesn't break? the idea is to postpone any subsequent call to this `runPromise` function until the first one finishes

Comment: @Federkun Actually mutating global `promise` and `error` variables seems to be the whole purpose of this function?

Comment: @Bergi yes, exactly

Comment: @Bergi I don't really understand, how my code is related to the antipattern you sent link to. could you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that in the `if (promise)` case, the promise returned by `runPromise` is never `res()`olved. `return`ing from the executor callback doesn't do anything. You could fix this by doing

```
const runPromise = (value) => new Promise((res) => {
    if (!error) {
        console.log("resolve immediately without error")
        res()
    } else if (promise) {
        promise.then(() => {
            console.log("resolve after waiting for previous promise")
            res(runPromise(value))
        })
    } else {
        promise = new Promise((res2) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                promise = null
                error = false
                res2()
                console.log("resolve after timeout")
                res()
            }, 1000)
        })
    }
})
```

but really you should just avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it), which caused this mistake in the first place. Don't call `then`, `new Promise` or `runPromise()` inside that outer `new Promise` executor! Instead use

```js
let error = true
let promise = null

function runPromise(value) {
    if (!error) {
        console.log(value, "resolve immediately without error")
        return Promise.resolve();
    } else if (promise) {
        console.log(value, "defer until promise")
        // now this `return` works as expected
        return promise.then(() => {
            console.log(value, "trying again")
            return runPromise(value) 
        })
    } else {
        console.log(value, "starting timeout")
        promise = new Promise(res2 => {
            setTimeout(res2, 1000)
        }).then(() => {
            promise = null
            error = false
            console.log(value, "waited for timeout")
        });
        return promise;
    }
}

runPromise(1).then(() => { console.log(1) })
runPromise(2).then(() => { console.log(2) })
runPromise(3).then(() => { console.log(3) })
```

Comment: That polling is unnecessary though

Comment: @JonasWilms Yes, I was just trying to show a cleaned up version that follows the same approach as the OP and fixed the error. Whether that is a (good) solution to the actual problem of the OP (or whether he would've needed a queue) I cannot say.

Answer (score 0):

You more or less have endless recursion here. Once you've set `promise =` the first time, `if(promise)` will always enter, and it will always attach another `.then` callback, that when called, just executes the same function again and again. It will also never call `res()`.

I'd generally seperate concerns here: Have one function build up the promise chain and let it take a task function that gets called with the value provided:

```
 let queue = Promise.resolve(); // no need for null, let it always be a promise

 function runTask(task, ...args) {
  return queue = queue.then(() => task(...args));
 }
```

Then write another function, that represents a task, e.g. in your case it's a function that waits a tick:

```
 function waitTask(n) { return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1000, n)); }

runTask(waitTask, 1);
runTask(waitTask, 2);
```

```js
let queue = Promise.resolve();

function runTask(task, ...args) {
  return queue = queue.then(() => task(...args));
}


function waitTask(n) { return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1000, n)); }

runTask(waitTask, 1).then(console.log);
runTask(waitTask, 2).then(console.log);
```

Comment: OP also sets `error = false` though which will make the function take the first branch, not the `if (promise)` one